# Send file to printer, nothing is printed

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing

I have this requirement where I must print a receipt from a Web Application. I've found the way to get the data in a String, generate a temporary text file, send it to the printer and delete the file. Everything is good except the print part, it generates nothing, a white document! I've checked my temp files before sending them to print and there is data there, maybe I'm sending the file in the wrong way or forgot to add a `PrintPageEventHandler` (I'm not so sure about this last one, or maybe I just don't know).

This is s what I've done:

```
private void printTextfile(String strFileName)
{
    //there is this standar that makes programmers declare variables at the 
    //beginning of the method and this "obj" and "str" things...
    PrintDocument objPrintDocument =null;
    String strPrinterName = string.Empty;
    //getting the printer name from web.config
    strPrinterName= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NOMBRE_IMPRESORA"];
    objPrintDocument = new PrintDocument();
    objPrintDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = strPrinterName;
    //the temp text file created and with data
    objPrintDocument.DocumentName = strFileName;
    //I guess don't need this because I've setted up the file name (it is reachable)
    //objPrintDocument.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.printTextFileHandler);
    //send the file to the printer (this works)
    objPrintDocument.Print();
    //ok, now I've check my physic file and it has nothing in it!
}
```

Please tell me if there is another way to do it, I just need to see the data printed. Note: I'm not using white forecolor or something like that, the printer can receive like 1 MB text and just print 1 page with nothing in it.

Comment: when you debug this are you getting a value back for strPrinterName or a null value..?

Comment: Where is the code that sends data to the printer? You are setting the DocumentName and then call Print, but this will not print anything.

Comment: @DJKRAZE there are no errors or else the printer couldn't print any file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a print page event handler that outputs your data to the printer.
If `strFileName` is the file name containing the data, then

- Open the file in the code above saving the streamreader in a global
  instance var.
- Add the page event handler
- Close the stream at exit

I think that this [example in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx) fits exactly

If you look at the documentation in MSDN about [DocumentName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.documentname.aspx) property you will find this statement

```
The DocumentName property does not specify the file to print.  
Rather, you specify the output to print by handling the PrintPage event.  
For an example, see the PrintDocument class overview.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader filetoprint;
              filetoprint = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"D:\\m.txt");
              printDocument1.Print();
              filetoprint.Close();
        }
```