# Print multiple files with same printer setting

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printdialog

I am currently opening the `PrintDialog` where user can select printer setting and do the printing.

At the moment I am using below code

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder);
foreach (var file in files)
{
     var pdoc = new PrintDocument();

     var pdi = new PrintDialog
               {
                  Document = pdoc
               };
     if (pdi.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      {
         pdoc.DocumentName = file;
         pdoc.Print();
      }
 }
```

Is there a way to send all the files to the printer by using `PrintDialog` once. So the user can select the folder and set one print setting for all the documents inside the folder and then do the printing?

Answer (score 1):

Try this sample code:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder);
if (files.Length != 0)
{
    using (var pdoc = new PrintDocument())
    using (var pdi = new PrintDialog { Document = pdoc, UseEXDialog = true })
    {
        if (pdi.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pdoc.PrinterSettings = pdi.PrinterSettings;
            // ************************************
            // Pay attention to the following line:
            pdoc.PrintPage += pd_PrintPage;
            // ************************************
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                pdoc.DocumentName = file;
                pdoc.Print();
            }
        }
    }
}

// The PrintPage event is raised for each page to be printed.
private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
{
    string file = ((PrintDocument)sender).DocumentName; // Current file name 
    // Do printing of the Document
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hey, just tried printing the file. It does print but nothing on the paper. It just empty!! When I tried by opening the document and print, it does print fine. Am I missing something?

Comment: Was the `PrintDialog` shown? If not, set the dialog's property `UseEXDialog = true`. I've updated the sample to reflect this.

Comment: Also you need to implement your printing in the `pdoc.PrintPage` event handler. Sample was updated.

Comment: Yes, the print dialog came up I can set the printer setting and print. But output is empty paper

Comment: Please pay attention to the `pdoc.PrintPage` event handler in my updated code sample. I've highlighted it by the comments. Was this handler set when tested?

Comment: No I haven't implemented the event. What should I do in the event?  Something like   `var info = new ProcessStartInfo(((PrintDocument)sender).DocumentName);  info.Verb = "Print"; Process.Start(info);` ?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty, No, even if action "Print" is associated with that file type, the printer settings will not be taken into account. You can use "Printto" verb to specify a printer to print to. But it's another question: "How to print file of specific type?" You can find the answer on the SO: [link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002346/print-file-with-net), [link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856833/print-pdf-file-and-doc-file-using-c-sharp), [link 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619232/send-file-to-printer-nothing-is-printed) etc

Comment: Yes, I have seen similar question. But it only uses the printer name only. Not the printer settings

Comment: To use the settings, you need to completely implement your own printing in the `PrintPage` handler. In other words, you need to programmatically draw everything what you want to see on a paper. I doubt that an another way exists.